# Factory reset for every Cyanogenmod Update?

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates

I plan to install Cyanogenmod on my new Android phone. For this first install, I've to do a factory reset - what's no problem on a factory new phone.
But do I have to perform this factory reset on every minor and major update of the mod in the next month and years - and loosing all my app settings, logins, game highscores etc. again and again?
Or does the Cyanogenmod update behave like a normal Android update (just a little bit downloading, rebooting and continue with all apps and settings as before)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking **you don't have to perform a factory reset when downloading a newer build**. The flashable zip should perform all wipes by itself if it is necessary (only certain partitions are affected - your data should be safe). Many developers include an OTA(Over-The-Air)Update Application so you can comfortably download and install the new build with 1-3 clicks. It depends on which device and which custom rom you are using.

In most cases you only have to perform a factory reset

1. when you're performing a fresh installation of CM
2. the android version changes(factory reset may not be needed but it is adviced most of the times)
3. when something goes wrong :)

The best thing to do is to make regular backups and save them on your computer - this way you won't loose much.

Comment: the factory reset for case 2 would be ok, if there are tools/services to restore really all apps+settings if the phone is rooted. Don't know those tools from my former Nexus 4

Comment: @Konrad [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=de) is probably the most used app for app-backups. You can select which apps you want to backup, if you want to backup the app+all of its data and more options. Very reliable and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can either update manually or using installer instructions

Quoting from Cyanogenmod official site [updating](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Updating) related to **manual**
Updates

> If you are doing a major update (such as from CM 7 to CM 10) or wish to clear the device's data partion, select Clear data partition or Factory Reset (depending on the recovery menu you are using)

Again from [release versioning](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Release_Versioning)

> CyanogenMod 9 - 10.2 build tags-
>   CyanogenMod 9 through 10.2 were qualified with tags: Experimental, Nightly, Release Candidate, and Stable. The Snapshot tag was added with the introduction of M builds in CyanogenMod 10.2. These tags were meant to indicate a build's suitability for general use.
>
> Nightly: usually generated every 24 hours, experimental, newest features, unstable
>   Experimental: testing version requested by device maintainers to evaluate specific changes
>   M Snapshot: milestone snapshot, more stable than a nightly but potentially some issues
>   Release Candidate: last builds before stable release, few minor issues, mostly stable, and safe for daily use
>   Stable: most stable version available, all or nearly all issues resolved

Nightlies are not [recommended](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/about) unless you can handle issues arising out of it

> These ROMs are largely untested, and as advised by CyanogenMod, not meant for use for an average user.

To answer your question now, avoid nightly/ experimental/ snapshot  builds, install only stable builds and update as recommended by CM installer or manually as highlighted.

***Generally* minor updates and nightly builds do not need factory reset**

This is about official builds. If you are sourcing your build from other developer forums follow their instructions